# Move a specific number of emails from shared Outlook folder

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

Every few days I manually move a specified number of emails from a shared network mailbox to subfolders of team managers. They want them moved from oldest to newest. Both the managers and the number can change each time.

I wrote a script for moving a small number of emails with a specific subject line in the folder to a subfolder to be worked by a certain group.

I have tried to adapt this to my current task.

```vb
Sub Moverdaily()

    On Error GoTo errHandler

    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim objNS As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim olFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim msg As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim manager= As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim cell,start,finish,rng   As Range
    Dim countE,countM  As Integer
    Dim emcount, casecount, movedcount
    Set rng = Range(Range("A2"), Range("A2").End(xlDown))
    Set olApp = Outlook.Application
    Set objNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set olFolder = objNS.Folders("Documents").Folders("Inbox")
    Set manager = objNS.Folders("Document").Folders("Inbox").Folders("Manager")
    Set finish = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Mover").Range("I11")
    Set start = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Mover").Range("I10")
    start.Value = Format(Now, "hh:mm:ss")
    Set emcount = Range("I12")
    Set casecount = Range("I13")
    Set movedcount = Range("I14")

    countM = 0
    countE = 0

    For i = olFolder.Items.count To 1 Step -1  
        For Each cell In rng
            If (cell.Text = (onlyDigits(msg.Subject))) Then
                msg.move manager 
                countM = 1 + countM
                cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Moved"
            End If
        Next
        countE = 1 + countE
    Next

    finish.Value = Format(Now, "hh:mm:ss")
    emcount.Value = countE
    casecount.Value = rng.count
    movedcount.Value = countM

errHandler:
    MsgBox ("Error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description)
    Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Chris, welcome to SO. If you take a little tour of the questions asked and well answered here, you'll see it is better to post the parts of the code you think must be improved.
Take your time to format and rephrase your question please. Here I think you could try reducing the size of your problem by splitting into smaller bits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, do not use "for each" with a collection that you change - `MailItem.Mpve` removes an itemn from that collection. Use a `for i = Items.Count to 1 step -1` instead.

Secondly, do not loop through all item - if you already know the entry ids (rngarry), simply call `Namespace.GetItemfromID`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply i am still having a hard time with this problem i have edited both my question and my code example to better try to explain what i am trying to do

Comment: And what is the exact problem that you are trying to solve at the moment?

Comment: thank you, your feedback allowed me to find a solution to my problem